# DX10 setfullscreenstate not working on second monitor

Tags: directx, fullscreen, directx-10, multiple-monitors, first-chance-exception

I have two display monitors connected to my pc.

I am using DirectX 10. I have a basic app, when I press space button I call;

```
swapChain->SetFullscreenState(true, 0);
```

to make it fullscreen.

It works well on my main monitor, but when I move the app to other monitor and press space button it does not work. Also throws first-chance exception.

Is it enough to just call SetFullscreenState function ? Or do I have to make sth else ?
Thanks for help.

***Edit :*** I solved this problem. 
You must assign your monitor to an IDXGIOutput type variable and pass it to SetFullscreenState function as second parameter.

```
swapChain->SetFullscreenState(true, &curr_monitor);
```

Comment: Also, fullscreen on second monitor is not working with Alt+Enter key combination(default DirectX feature).

Comment: What's the first-chance exception?